# How to react to itemRangeMoved in RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

`RecyclerView.Adapter` seems to quite nicely match requirements of `ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback`. It has matching prototypes for required methods: `itemRangeChanged`, `itemRangeInserted` and `itemRangeRemoved`. However, it does not have matching method for `itemRangeMoved`.

What is the valid way of notifying `RecyclerView.Adapter` about moving range of items?

For a reminder, prototype of this method in `ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback` looks like following:

```
public void itemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount)
```

My options are, I guess:

1. Notify about removing items (`fromPosition`, `itemCount`) and then about inserting items (`toPosition`, `itemCount`), or
2. Loop through `itemCount` and notify about moved single item (Adapter's `notifyItemMoved`), or
3. Notify about items changed from min(`fromPosition`, `toPosition`) through max(`fromPosition + itemCount`, `toPosition + itemCount`)?